# Изменение фона строк в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Можно ли в Android Studio сделать, чтобы фон строк, корректируемых в текущем сеансе, выделялся другим цветом?

Как в Nodepad++, например. ЭТО ОЧЕНЬ, ОЧЕНЬ УДОБНО! )))

Про контроль версий слышал, но это не удобно и громоздко для оперативной работы.  Замедляет компиляцию, занимает доп. дисковое пространство, дает, порой, совершенно лишний функционал...

Может, плагины какие есть?

Comment: скачать тему, в которой это есть

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то это есть в Android Studio. Только студия помечает не фон строки, а с левой стороны от строки ставит соответствующие значки, по которым видно где была модификация исходников:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробнее здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Не могу найти настройку в File > Setting > Editor. Какая вкладка? Подскажите, пжлс